# What's the linux command to get the stack of a running process without having to attach to it in a debugger?

Tags: linux, debugging, stack-trace, shortcut

What's the linux command to get the stack of a running process without having to attach to it in a debugger?

I've seen someone do this before, but do not recall the command they used to do it.

This is really handy as a quick way to see what your program is doing without going through the overhead of attaching to it in a debugger to get the stack trace to see where it is currently at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the command is /usr/bin/pstack as shown at man page pstack(1).